Go to Login page directly (Spring Security + auth0)
I have created login function with Spring Security' and Auth0(okta)`.
However, I'm confused about why the /login uri redirects to a login confirmation page like the one shown below.

I want to go directly to the login input page when the /login uri executed.

Does anyone know how to do this ? thanks.
fyi
this is my Spring Security configuration.
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig(
    private val oidcUserDetailService: OidcUserDetailService,
    private val logoutHandler: LogoutHandler
) {

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .oauth2Login { oauth2Login ->
                oauth2Login
                    .userInfoEndpoint { userInfoEndpoint ->
                        userInfoEndpoint.oidcUserService(oidcUserDetailService)}
            }.csrf { csrf ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**")
                csrf.disable()
            }
        return http.build()
    }
}

I added .loginPage("/login")  in the security configuration, but this caused too many redirects error. I want the /login URI to go to the email/password input page.
